# How to identify (in Windows) another computer's IP address on a network of 2

Tags: networking, ip-address, windows-networking

I have two computers networked to each other via a crossover cable, a laptop I have full access to and a headless late model industrial PC; my laptop is able to obtain a DHCP address via this connection, but how can I identify the IP address of the industrial PC?

Comment: [`arp -a`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/arp)

Comment: https://www.pcwdld.com/how-to-scan-network-for-ip-addresses